# How can I calculate an equation with decimal point exponents on a primitive calculator?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, programming

By primitive calculator, I really mean a type of scripting that can only calculated by adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing numbers that can be either negative or positive but not a decimal.

With the script, I can't just input an equation. I will have to write out each step manually. Thankfully it shouldn't too hard (planning to do exponents by making it multiply itself recursively).

As an example equation, I have $1-(1-0.50)^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}$

(For context, it's the equation Pokemon Go uses to calculate whether a pokemon will be caught or not- modified a bit so that it fits what I am trying to do. Contains Base Capture Rate and Throw, Ball, and Berry modifiers. https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Catch_rate_(GO))

At first, I thought I could just multiply everything by 100 to make them all whole and then divide it by 100 after but the issue that I found was that it does not work well with exponents.

With experimenting, I found that something like $100-\frac{(100-50)^\frac{(15*15*13)}{1000}}{10000}$ works, but sometimes it gives me numbers way over 100 when the goal of the equation is to get a number between 1 and 100.

The way the script works is each line can compare two values, the second(source) affecting the first(target) depending on which operation you specify.

List of operations:
"+=" Addition: Add source's score to that of target
"-=" Subtraction: Subtract source's score from that of target
"*=" Multiplication: Set target's score to the product of target's and source's scores
"/=" (Integer) Division: Divide target's score by source's score, and use the result (rounded down) to set the target score.
"%=" Modulus: Divide target's score by source's score, and use the remainder to set the target score
"=" Assign: Set target's score to that of source
"<" Min: Set target's score to source's score only if source has the lesser score.
">" Max: Set target's score to source's score only if source has the greater score.
"><" Swaps target's and source's scores

Essentially I have been sticking to multiplying the exponent's values together and then I will recursively multiply the value that has the exponent by itself however many times the exponent is. But how can I do this while retaining the original equation's goal? Am I doing this all wrong and thinking too much when there's an easier way to do the same thing?

Comment: Your suggested "translation" is not equal to the original formula. But if you can divide to get non-integral numbers, why not replace each number like $1234.5678$ by $$\frac{12345678}{10000}$$ separately?

Comment: the issue I have is that I can't really divide the numbers that I multiplied out of decimals until the very end of the equation since I cant use decimals during the calculation, since the scripting language I am using rounds all decimal numbers up, per calculation, every time it encounters them.

you can see that I made an exception to that rule when multiplying the exponential values together since I will have to recursively multiply the value with the exponent by itself and you cant run recursive functions only a 0.5 (or whatever decimal value) amount of times.

Comment: What about $\frac{{10^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}}-(10 - 5)^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}}{10^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}}$ ? Or $\frac{{100^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}}-(100 - 50)^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}}{100^{1.5\cdot1.5\cdot1.3}}$

Comment: again, the issue is I can't use decimals at all. only the end result of the equation can have a decimal as it will be rounded up anyway.

Comment: Maybe you can use the Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ and $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$ to approximate it. Everything should come out to be a polynomial, if you choose an appropriate common denominator (which might be quite big), everything should turn out to be an integer.